# Windows 10 IoT to play videos?

Tags: pi-2, video, streaming-video

The question is rather simple. Is there a way for me to use the Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) to play videos on a monitor using Windows 10 IoT?

I've been googling around for 2 hours, but I haven't found anything on the subject. I know there are media players for other operating Systems, but I haven't read about any players working on Windows 10 IoT.

Does anybody know of a pre-existing solution? Or will I have to write my own program?

Comment: If video playback is what your after I strongly recommend an OS like XBMC.

Comment: Thanks. I figured Raspbian was the way to go and uninstalled Windows 10 IoT a few hours after I asked that question.

Comment: Frankly, I am disgusted at Microsft for neglecting this sooo long. More than 18 months. I am going to dedicate my self over the next few months to punch them in the nad's and get this fixed, done and dusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no decent video player for Windows 10 IoT. I simply switched over to Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

this might do it....or at least be a start

https://www.hackster.io/windowsiot/video-recorder-app-on-windows-10-iot-core-ec9309

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found this Media Player on GitHub, would have copy the text and create the app in VS 2017 as it is read only, but it is better than trying to write one from scratch.

https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreMediaPlayer